# Extract contact phone number by name

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am trying to get the phone number of a contact by his name, (The name is a String) ,does anyone have an idea how?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you; Replace People.NAME by the name you want.

```
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            People.NAME,
            People.NUMBER
         };

    Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection,
    null, null, People.NAME + " ASC");
    c.moveToFirst();
    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(People.NAME);
    int numCol = c.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);

    int nContacts = c.getCount();
    do{
        // Do your work here
    } while(c.moveToNext());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Should work for you.
Returning List of all numbers assigned to this contact

```
   public static List<String> getContactByName(Context context,
         String name) {
         String[] mProjection = {
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

         Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
               mProjection,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"
                     + name + "%'", null, null);

         List<String> listOfPhonesAssignedToThisName = new ArrayList<String>();
         while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            listOfPhonesAssignedToThisName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DISPLAY_NAME")));
         }
         return listOfPhonesAssignedToThisName;
   }
```

Note:
this function is comparing everything that looks **LIKE** your display name.
If you want to find exactly the right person you need to tweak part:

**ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"**
                         + name + "%'", null, null);

to:
**ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '"**
                         + name + "'", null, null);